# how to generate sequence number for repeating rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (df) where I have to generate sequence numbers for repeated rows (i.e., rows with similar values). For example, following is my df:

```
P_Id    Time_Point     Date       
B001    0           2015-07-22
B001    0           2015-07-22
B001    0           2015-07-22
B001    0           2015-07-22
B001    0           2015-07-22
B001    3           2015-10-01
B001    3           2015-10-01
B001    3           2015-10-01
B001    3           2015-10-01
B001    3           2015-10-01
B001    12          2016-08-01
B001    12          2016-08-01
B001    12          2016-08-01
B001    12          2016-08-01
B001    12          2016-08-01
```

Now if you see there are repeating rows for the same id (001), with a similar time point and similar date. I would like to have another column where each pattern have a sequence number. The resulting df should look like:

```
P_Id    Time_Point     Date        Seq     
B001    0           2015-07-22      1         
B001    0           2015-07-22      2         
B001    0           2015-07-22      3         
B001    0           2015-07-22      4         
B001    0           2015-07-22      5         
B001    3           2015-10-01      1          
B001    3           2015-10-01      2
B001    3           2015-10-01      3
B001    3           2015-10-01      4
B001    12          2016-08-01      1
B001    12          2016-08-01      2
B001    12          2016-08-01      3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) scalar `1`:

```
df['Seq'] = df.groupby(['P_Id','Time_Point','Date']).cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
    P_Id  Time_Point        Date  Seq
0   B001           0  2015-07-22    1
1   B001           0  2015-07-22    2
2   B001           0  2015-07-22    3
3   B001           0  2015-07-22    4
4   B001           0  2015-07-22    5
5   B001           3  2015-10-01    1
6   B001           3  2015-10-01    2
7   B001           3  2015-10-01    3
8   B001           3  2015-10-01    4
9   B001           3  2015-10-01    5
10  B001          12  2016-08-01    1
11  B001          12  2016-08-01    2
12  B001          12  2016-08-01    3
13  B001          12  2016-08-01    4
14  B001          12  2016-08-01    5
```

Comment: What does `cumcount` stand for?

Comment: @Szabolcs - It count groups, check [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

Comment: @szabolcs it stands for "cumulative count". It's part of a family of functions that includes cumulative sum, cumulative product, etc.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp - Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Interesting choice of name though.

Comment: @Szabolcs - Do you think my nick? ;)